# Data Frame write append approach

Tags: apache-spark

This works fine for me when saving data to mySQL:

```
jdbcDF.write
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", "jdbc:mysql://db4free.net:3306/gedmysql")
  .option("dbtable", "newtable2")
  .option("user", "user")
  .option("password", "pswd")
  .save()
```

However, I cannot seem to find the append / overwrite equivalent in **this** format. I see various things, but they do not seem to work.

E.g. **.mode(SaveMode.Append)** instead of **.save()** runs, but no change to the mySQL database. There looks to me to be 2 styles to use, what I quote I thought was new in 2.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to do it the **"other way"** from what I can see, i.e. :

```
jdbcDF.write.mode("append").jdbc(url, table, prop)
```

.save only an option on **that** format I showed in question.

It is what it is.